# Recording Yamaha Keyboard Audio on Macbook Pro

Tags: recording, software, keyboard, audio, mac

I have a Yamaha P45 whose audio I want to record on my Macbook Pro. I followed instructions from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GSf_MEDzJsA) so to summarize:

I have a 3.5mm stereo y-splitter plugged into the Yamaha P45, and two patch cables running from the y-splitter: one into my Audio-Technica headphones, and the other into a StarTech TRRS adapter that I have plugged into my Macbook Pro. When I play keys on the piano, I can hear them in my headphones so the y-splitter probably isn't the issue.

The only input audio I see listed when I try recording with any software is the built-in microphone (internal), so the keyboard's audio isn't getting picked up by the Macbook Pro.

As an aside, I do notice that if I plug my Apple headphones into the headphones port of the y-splitter I can receive audio output from the Macbook Pro.... so does that mean the y-splitter should be able to capture the keyboard's input or that it actually is capturing the keyboard's input but the Macbook Pro just isn't recognizing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: I tried a few advanced settings on my MacBook Pro 2017 in Launchpad and audio input only has the built in mic as an option. The headphone jack is now just that, no line input option. I assume you have a fairly recent MacBook. I found this on an Apple support site: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7086508

Sorry for the bad news. I’m not surprised Apple has removed such a basic function from their laptops. Your best bet if cost is a issue is to look for a used audio interface. Make sure you check for compatibility with your machine and OS. There are some inexpensive usb-C adapters that give you audio as well but these are probably sketchy.